# sas date - convert today() into yyyymmdd format

Tags: date, format, sas

How do I convert a SAS date such as `"30JUL2009"d` into `YYYYMMDD` format (eg 20090730)?

So for instance:

```
data _null_;
  format test ?????;
  test=today();
  put test=;
run;
```

Would give me "test=20090730" in the log...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
data _null_;
    format test yymmddn8.;
    test=today();
    put test=;
run;
```

[YYMMDDxw. documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000589916.htm)

Comment: Umm. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but format that works for me is: format test yymmddn8.;

Comment: Thanks @pinegulf, I updated the answer. Only took 8 years for someone to catch that!

Answer (score 14):

```
%let expectdate1=%sysfunc(putn(%eval(%sysfunc(today())-1),yymmddn8.));
```

You want to use the format yymmddn8.  The 'n' means *no separator*.

Per http://support.sas.com/kb/24/610.html you can specify B for blank, C for colon, D for dash, N for no separator, P for period, or S for slash.

Answer (score 3):

There is this one that should do the trick too

```
%let today=%sysfunc(today(),yymmddn8.);
%put &today.;
```

Everything on the link below

https://communities.sas.com/thread/60111

Answer (score 2):

here's how I did it in macro, but surely there must be a format??!!!

```
%let today=%sysfunc(compress(%sysfunc(today(),yymmddd10.),'-'));
```

its weird - the INFORMAT yymmdd8. gives YYYYMMDD result, whereas the FORMAT yymmdd8. gives a YY-MM-DD result!!

Answer (score 0):

You can see all date and time formats in Help tab when you enter 'date' to Index tab and then selecr 'date and time formats'